# Cloudfoundry Laravel "Could not open input file: artisan"

Tags: laravel, cloud-foundry, buildpack

I am trying to push a Laravel application with the CF CLI.
I created a new Laravel application, a manifest.yml and tried to deploy it but got the error *"Could not open input file: artisan"*.

All I did was :

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel app`

```
manifest.yml
---
applications:
- name: laravel-test
  memory: 512M
  buildpacks:
    - php_buildpack_v4_6_13
```

`cf push`

Here's the result of the command :

```
Updating with these attributes...
  ---
  applications:
  - name: laravel-test
    memory: 512M
+   default-route: true
    buildpacks:
      php_buildpack_v4_6_13
Manifest applied
Packaging files to upload...
Uploading files...
 8.72 MiB / 8.72 MiB [==============================================================================================================================================================================] 100.00% 2s

Waiting for API to complete processing files...

Staging app and tracing logs...
   Downloading php_buildpack_v4_6_13...
   Downloaded php_buildpack_v4_6_13 (509.6M)
   Cell 49e76781-b3ee-46da-b80b-b703787a9809 creating container for instance 217c9e0f-9274-4750-91d1-e6342a087455
   Security group rules were updated
   Cell 49e76781-b3ee-46da-b80b-b703787a9809 successfully created container for instance 217c9e0f-9274-4750-91d1-e6342a087455
   Downloading app package...
   Downloaded app package (24.5M)
   -------> Buildpack version 4.6.13
   Installing HTTPD
   HTTPD 2.4.58
   Downloaded [file:///tmp/buildpacks/bf04536342a2b09e39e9b4fc737b7c41/dependencies/https___buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org_dependencies_httpd_httpd_2.4.58_linux_x64_cflinuxfs4_bed46d20.tgz] to [/tmp]
   Installing PHP
   PHP 8.2.13
   Downloaded [file:///tmp/buildpacks/bf04536342a2b09e39e9b4fc737b7c41/dependencies/https___buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org_dependencies_php_php_8.2.13_linux_x64_cflinuxfs4_300ddf44.tgz] to [/tmp]
   Downloaded [file:///tmp/buildpacks/bf04536342a2b09e39e9b4fc737b7c41/dependencies/https___buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org_dependencies_php_php_8.2.13_linux_x64_cflinuxfs4_300ddf44.tgz] to [/tmp]
   Downloaded [file:///tmp/buildpacks/bf04536342a2b09e39e9b4fc737b7c41/dependencies/https___buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org_dependencies_composer_composer_2.6.5_linux_noarch_any-stack_9a18e1a3.phar] to [/tmp]
   Installing dependencies from lock file
   Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
   Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 37 removals
   - Removing theseer/tokenizer (1.2.2)
   - Removing symfony/yaml (v6.4.0)
   - Removing spatie/laravel-ignition (2.3.3)
   - Removing spatie/ignition (1.11.3)
   - Removing spatie/flare-client-php (1.4.3)
   - Removing spatie/backtrace (1.5.3)
   - Removing sebastian/version (4.0.1)
   - Removing sebastian/type (4.0.0)
   - Removing sebastian/recursion-context (5.0.0)
   - Removing sebastian/object-reflector (3.0.0)
   - Removing sebastian/object-enumerator (5.0.0)
   - Removing sebastian/lines-of-code (2.0.2)
   - Removing sebastian/global-state (6.0.1)
   - Removing sebastian/exporter (5.1.1)
   - Removing sebastian/environment (6.0.1)
   - Removing sebastian/diff (5.1.0)
   - Removing sebastian/complexity (3.2.0)
   - Removing sebastian/comparator (5.0.1)
   - Removing sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (3.0.0)
   - Removing sebastian/code-unit (2.0.0)
   - Removing sebastian/cli-parser (2.0.0)
   - Removing phpunit/phpunit (10.5.5)
   - Removing phpunit/php-timer (6.0.0)
   - Removing phpunit/php-text-template (3.0.1)
   - Removing phpunit/php-invoker (4.0.0)
   - Removing phpunit/php-file-iterator (4.1.0)
   - Removing phpunit/php-code-coverage (10.1.11)
   - Removing phar-io/version (3.2.1)
   - Removing phar-io/manifest (2.0.3)
   - Removing nunomaduro/collision (v7.10.0)
   - Removing myclabs/deep-copy (1.11.1)
   - Removing mockery/mockery (1.6.7)
   - Removing laravel/sail (v1.26.3)
   - Removing laravel/pint (v1.13.7)
   - Removing hamcrest/hamcrest-php (v2.0.1)
   - Removing filp/whoops (2.15.4)
   - Removing fakerphp/faker (v1.23.0)
   Generating optimized autoload files
   > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
   > @php artisan package:discover --ansi
   Could not open input file: artisan
   Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
   -----> Composer command failed
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/tmp/buildpacks/bf04536342a2b09e39e9b4fc737b7c41/scripts/compile.py", line 55, in <module>
   .from_build_pack('lib/additional_commands')
   File "/tmp/buildpacks/bf04536342a2b09e39e9b4fc737b7c41/lib/build_pack_utils/builder.py", line 212, in extensions
   process_extension(path, ctx, 'compile', process, args=[self])
   File "/tmp/buildpacks/bf04536342a2b09e39e9b4fc737b7c41/lib/build_pack_utils/utils.py", line 69, in process_extension
   success(getattr(extn, to_call)(*args))
   File "/tmp/buildpacks/bf04536342a2b09e39e9b4fc737b7c41/extensions/composer/extension.py", line 444, in compile
   return composer.compile(install)
   File "/tmp/buildpacks/bf04536342a2b09e39e9b4fc737b7c41/lib/extension_helpers.py", line 154, in compile
   self._compile(install)
   File "/tmp/buildpacks/bf04536342a2b09e39e9b4fc737b7c41/extensions/composer/extension.py", line 196, in _compile
   self.run()
   File "/tmp/buildpacks/bf04536342a2b09e39e9b4fc737b7c41/extensions/composer/extension.py", line 343, in run
   *self._ctx['COMPOSER_INSTALL_OPTIONS'])
   File "/tmp/buildpacks/bf04536342a2b09e39e9b4fc737b7c41/extensions/composer/extension.py", line 390, in run
   shell=True)
   File "/tmp/buildpacks/bf04536342a2b09e39e9b4fc737b7c41/lib/build_pack_utils/runner.py", line 109, in stream_output
   raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
   build_pack_utils.runner.CalledProcessError: Command '<open file '<fdopen>', mode 'w' at 0x7fe8a9cb1ae0>' returned non-zero exit status 1
BuildpackCompileFailed - App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
FAILED
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to resolve this problem ? I've searched but I didn't find it anywhere else.

Also, I can't try to change the buildpack to run some tests, custom buildpacks are not allowed where I am.

Comment: Something looks odd with Composer. It is removing all of your packages. Not sure why that's happening, but it could account for why the command fails, since it's uninstalling a bunch of stuff.

Comment: it is certain that your artisan is not present at root of your project. You need to update your `composer.json` to include correct path for your artisan. for your reference you can find this under `composer.json`>>`scripts`>>`"post-autoload-dump"`

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the error is occurring during the `composer` install phase when it's trying to run the `post-autoload-dump` event, specifically the `@php artisan package:discover --ansi` command. The error message indicates that it could not open the input file: `artisan`.

The Laravel application expects the artisan script to be present in the root directory. However, in a CF environment, the application is staged in a different directory, and the artisan script might not be accessible.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

### Check Directory Structure

Ensure that the `artisan` script is present in the root directory of your Laravel application. When you create a new Laravel application using `composer create-project`, the `artisan` script should be automatically generated.

### Modify Composer Scripts:

Update your `composer.json` file to include the correct paths. Open `composer.json` and look for the "scripts" section. It should have something like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ]
},
```

Ensure that the `@php artisan package:discover --ansi` command is correctly pointing to the `artisan` script. If needed, adjust the path to match the Cloud Foundry environment.

### Adjust Command in manifest.yml

You can optionally update your `manifest.yml` file to specify the correct start command. Instead of relying on the default command, you can explicitly define the command to run your Laravel application. For example:

```
applications:
  - name: laravel-test
    memory: 512M
    buildpacks:
      - php_buildpack_v4_6_13
    command: "php public/index.php" // assuming that your Laravel application's entry point is public/index.php
```

### Redeploy

After making these changes try redeploying and this should be enough.

*pardon any kind of syntax errors*